# Hibernate BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to use Hibernate in my Spring application but i've got an error on the project's deployment

```
Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'configurationClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration].
```

Here my dispatcher-servlet with the bean session factory :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd"
  default-autowire="byName">

<context:component-scan base-package="hibernateTest" />

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" 
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

And my hibernate-cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="hibernateTest.web.InventoryController" />
</session-factory>     
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I've many jars in my classpath and i thoutgh it doesn't miss anyone. Could you help me finding an issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the hibernate-annotations.jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration]

This is the reason, Can you check for this class in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

`org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration` is deprecated,

and all its functionality has been moved to `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`.

change your code

```
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration</value>
        </property>
```

Comment: Ok, then if i use it could i still use annotation ?

Comment: If i put this value i've got the follow error : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="hibernateTest.web.InventoryController"/>